# "went for a saunter" vs. "sauntered" - Two ways to say the same thing?

Tags: verbs, nouns, nominalization

Do

> They went for a saunter in the park.

and

> They sauntered in the park.

have the same meaning?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they mean pretty much the same thing. Moreover, there are a many other words that function as both a noun and verb, and we can do the same with those:

> They **strolled/walked/jaunted/jogged/walked** to the park.
>
> They went for a **stroll/walk/jaunt/jog/walk** to the park.

However, we need to be careful – this won't *always* work! For example, as a noun, "travel" is considered uncountable. So, we *can* say:

> They traveled to the park.

but we would **not** say:

> <strike>They went for a travel to the park</strike>.

Similarly, we might say:

> They took a trip to the park.

but we wouldn't say:

> They tripped through the park.

(Well, we could say that last one, but it would mean something different.)

Essentially, you need to consult a dictionary, and look carefully at the definitions for both the noun and verb forms of the word.

Comment: Just a note, the preposition in the question is "in" not "to".

Comment: Without getting bogged down in semantics, "went for a saunter" implies the express intention to "go for a saunter" whereas "they sauntered in their park" on their way somewhere else for example.

Comment: @Cat - I realize that, but I changed the preposition in my examples because I thought that _jaunt_ doesn't work as well with _in_. That said, the other four words would work fine with _in, to, at,_ or _through_. Nice catch.

Comment: @JMB - Maybe we *should* get bogged down in semantics. I won't pretend my answer settles the matter. If you have the time to elaborate on that in an answer, I think it'd be beneficial to both the O.P. and to the site.